# Google API with PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

**EDIT**

Issue solved. I missed to call session_start(). A really stupid mistake! :( But, now it works fine! \o/

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm trying to use Google API applying the recipe provided by Google at https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

Both client-side and server-side code works fine: I'm able to connect, the client sends information to the server (*/plus.php?storeToken*), the server authenticates, and I'm able to call `$objGooglePlusService->people->get('me');`

During this very first call, I'm able to get all the user information. I also store the token provided by Google servers with `$_SESSION['token'] = $objGoogleClient->getAccessToken();` in order to perform later requests. Then, trying to access */plus.php?getInfo* just after a successful access to */plus.php?storeToken*, I'm no more able to access user information. Even after calling `$objGoogleClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);` before trying to access user data. Instead an exception is raised :

> Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error
>   calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=324234fsfesf-es5uAK9wVhE3woiOp_lqEk:
>   (401) Invalid Credentials

I guess I missed something but I'm unable to figure out what. Could you, please, help me?

Thanks.

**PHP code for plus.php**

```
$objResponse = new stdClass();
$strCallback = NULL;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    $strCallback = 'showError';
    $objResponse->status = 500;
    $objResponse->message = 'Bad method';
} else {
    require_once 'lib/google/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'lib/google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
    require_once 'lib/xmas/Person.class.php';

    $objGoogleClient = new Google_Client();
    $objGoogleClient->setApplicationName('xmas');
    $objGoogleClient->setClientId('XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'); // Real credential are inserted in real environment.
    $objGoogleClient->setClientSecret('XXXX');
    $objGoogleClient->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
    $objGoogleClient->setDeveloperKey('XXXX');
    $objGooglePlusService = new Google_PlusService($objGoogleClient);

    $objResponse = new stdClass();

    if (isset($_GET['storeToken'])) {
        $strCode = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $objGoogleClient->authenticate($strCode);
        $strToken = $objGoogleClient->getAccessToken();
        $objToken = json_decode($strToken);

        // Verify the token
        $strRequestUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' . $objToken->access_token;
        $objGoogleHttpRequest = new Google_HttpRequest($strRequestUrl);

        $strTokenInfo = json_decode($objGoogleClient::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($objGoogleHttpRequest)->getResponseBody());

        if ($strTokenInfo->error) {
            // If there was an error in the token info, abort.
            $strCallback = 'showError';
            $objResponse->status = 500;
            $objResponse->message = $strTokenInfo->error;
        } elseif ($strTokenInfo->userid != $gPlusId) {
            // Make sure the token we got is for the intended user.
            $strCallback = 'showError';
            $objResponse->status = 401;
            $objResponse->message = "Le jeton associé à l'ID utilisateur ne correspond pas l'ID utilisateur fourni";
        } elseif ($strTokenInfo->audience != 'XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com') {
            // Make sure the token we got is for our app.
            $strCallback = 'showError';
            $objResponse->status = 401;
            $objResponse->message = "Le jeton associé à l'ID client ne correspond pas à celui de l'application";
        } else {
            // Store the token in the session for later use.
            $_SESSION['token'] = $strToken;
            $arrMe = $objGooglePlusService->people->get('me');

            $objPerson = \Xmas\Person::search($arrMe['id']);

            if (is_null($objPerson->getID())) {
                $objPerson->setGoogleID($arrMe['id']);
                $objPerson->setDisplayName($arrMe['displayName']);
                if (array_key_exists('name', $arrMe)) {
                    $objPerson->setFamilyName(array_key_exists('familyName', $arrMe['name']) ? $arrMe['name']['familyName'] : '');
                    $objPerson->setGivenName(array_key_exists('givenName', $arrMe['name']) ? $arrMe['name']['givenName'] : '');
                }
                $objPerson->setImage($arrMe['image']['url']);
                $objPerson->setURL($arrMe['url']);

                foreach ($arrMe['emails'] as $arrMailData) {
                    $objMail = new Xmas\Mail();
                    $objMail->setValue($arrMailData['value']);
                    $objMail->setType($arrMailData['type']);
                    $objPerson->addMail($objMail);
                }

                $objPerson->save();
            }

            $strCallback = 'getInfo';
            $objResponse->status = 200;
            $objResponse->message = 'Token stored';
            $objResponse->token = $strToken;
            $objResponse->me = $objGooglePlusService->people->get('me');

            $_SESSION['person'] = $objPerson;
        }
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $objGoogleClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    } else {
        $strCallback = 'showError';
        $objResponse->status = 402;
        $objResponse->message = 'Session expired';
    }

    if (isset($_GET['getInfo'])) {
        $arrMe = $objGooglePlusService->people->get('me');

        $strCallback = 'showInfo';
        $objResponse->status = 200;
        $objResponse->time = time();
        $objResponse->target = strtotime('2013-12-01 00:00:00');
        $objResponse->me = $arrMe;

        $intTime = time();
        if ($intTime < strtotime('2013-12-01 00:00:00')) {
            // STEP - MONTRE CHRONO 1
            $strCallback = 'showCountDown';
            $objResponse->status = 200;
            $objResponse->time = time();
            $objResponse->target = strtotime('2013-12-01 00:00:00');
            $objResponse->me = $arrMe;
        } elseif (($intTime >= strtotime('2013-12-01 00:00:00')) && ($intTime < strtotime('2013-12-14 00:00:00'))) {
            // STEP - DEMANDE COORDONNEES

            $strCallback = 'askPostal';
            $objResponse->status = 200;
            $objResponse->name = $arrMe['displayName'];
            $objResponse->mail = '';
            foreach ($arrMe['emails'] as $arrMailData) {
                if ($arrMailData['type'] == 'account') {
                    $objResponse->mail = $arrMailData['value'];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo ($strCallback ? "{$strCallback}(" . json_encode($objResponse) . ");" : json_encode($objResponse));
ob_flush();
```

Comment: You will want to reset your Google Console API key that you pasted here in the error code.

Comment: I'm not sure if this fixes your issue but the particular error message you have here uses a `key` for auth, which is app specific to try and authenticate a user resource. For `me` requests you need a users `access_token`.

Comment: Thanks for answering @abraham. I cannot figure out why a `key` is sent as I provide an `acces_token` (previously stored in `$_SESSION['token']`). Just wonder if i'm not missing something with online/offline mode. I cannot either figure out why is `$objGoogleClient->setRedirectUri('postmessage');` in the example code in Google API documentation.